# How come the Query in Management Portal of Azure didn't work?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, portal

I am trying out this exercise - http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-get-started/

Instead of connecting to SQL Server Management Studio 2014, I am using Query in Azure Management Portal. However, I am stuck in Step 7 at a very simple query - "Select * Person". I kept getting error message saying - Invalid object name 'Per'. What was done incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

I tried but I am unable to repro your issue. You could try open the saved query in a text editor and change the text there, then save and open the file again in the management portal. That may work.

Also, you could try using SSDT https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027  for a better development experience.

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
SELECT * FROM Person
```

Comment: Apologies, I missed out "FROM" when I was typing the previous post. I simply copied and pasted the script - "SELECT * From Person" to the query editor in Azure Management Portal and still resulted the same error - "Invalid object name 'Per'. I have saved the query and re-opened it in the query editor and noticed that the saved query displayed only "SELECT * From Per". It really puzzled me...how come the last few characters of the table named Person got truncated?